# Is there a way to say maven not to use timestamp for dependency resolution

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3, snapshot, artifactory

I am using MAVEN3 and I have a project XXX with version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and it is being uploaded to artifactory.I can find the jar uploaded to artifactory as XXX-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.

Another project YYY uses XXX-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar as its dependency and it is declared as

```
<dependency>
<groupId>...<...>
 <arti...>XXX</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to build YYY maven is trying to download XXX jar file from artifactory and it fails to find.

I get the following error

Could not resolve dependencies for project com......YYY:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com....XXX:jar:1.0.0-20130710.163046-1 in repo1 (https://artifactory.xxx.com/artifactory/REPO1)

I can see that it tries to download a jar with specific timestamp.How can I tell maven not to use timestamp to download my dependency.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for non-unique snapshots was removed in Maven 3 (see related [JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-4059)).

I found an [Artifactory document](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories) mentioning one way to handle this, near the bottom of the page.

My team has noticed problems if developers publishing snapshots to the same group/artifact in the snapshot repository are not all using the same Maven version.  Either everyone needs to stick with Maven 2, or everyone uses Maven 3.  Mixing doesn't work well.